# UICollectionView Get Rid of Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I just want my collection view to show the cells without any background. I can't imagine this being very difficult but i have tried `self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` and `self.collectionView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]];` both to no avail.

I've included a picture to try and demonstrate what I am looking for. The VC that encompasses this collection view has an imageView as its background, my end goal is to have the collectionView over it without any background color of its own. So it should just be collectionViewcell's on top of the imageView.

[image]

Comment: Setting color to clear should 100% work. Are you certain that .collectionView outlet is pointing to the object at the time you set the value? (that is, self.collectionView is not nil). Try putting a button with tap handler that sets value to blue or something. (Reason: you can let all loading/processing completely finish then tap button, allowing you to see if you are perhaps running your "set = clear" code at some point in the view lifecycle before everything is completely connected and all loading code has completed.)

Comment: So what I'm suggesting is that you have nil pointer, pointer that points to the wrong object, or some code running later in view load/appear lifecycle is overwriting value.

Comment: Try setting `cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor` to clear in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Also, what are your cell contents set to? Are the white areas the actual insets on the cell itself? Since everything in iOS defaults to white, set colors to red/blue/yellow to make it obvious which component is the one providing the color.  [Edit -- never mind, I see Pedros already pointed this out!]

Comment: It's either inset in the cell. try to set the cell.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; Also, you can change the size of the image itself.